# How to compute the integral of that area?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area

The area is given by  $ 0 \le x+y \le 4-(x-y)^2 $ ?
By magic the inequalities were transformed into 
$ 0 \le  \sqrt  2 \ u \le 4 - 2v^2 $
and after that computing the integral became almost trivial. I can "see" that those two inequalities are very similar and in fact work, however I don't really know or understand how to write this down properly without saying "The bible said so."
Well, first how do you proof that an area is shaped exactly like it is and that is fair to just substitute the variable as you please to make it look nicer? 
So how would you approach this problem without relying on magic, plotting etc. ?

Comment: What integral exactly do you want to compute?

Comment: I am not sure, how to word it correctly. That above given inequality gives me an area and I had to find out how big is, which meant for me integration of that area over x and y. The inequality in that form is not too nice to compute, so I changed it into the second equality given above and then it became easier to figure out the bounds etc. 
(I would be very happy, if someone understands what I want to do and could show me also a proper way of writing that down)

Answer (score 1):

You mean $\sqrt2 \, u$, not $2 \sqrt{u}$, don't you? That would make more sense, since the change of variables
$$
u=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}
,
v=\frac{y-x}{\sqrt2}
$$
is just a rotation of the coordinate system by 45 degrees, and that doesn't change the area.

Comment: oh, right ty, I correct it above

Comment: Is there a proper and intuitive way to understand that this change of variables is actually a rotation by 45° ? I can even see/believe that $ \frac{1}{ \sqrt 2} $ doesn't appear by randomness, as it is $ \sin 45° $, maybe I am just too blind to actually see it.

Comment: It's a standard thing in linear algebra courses. But if you haven't taken linear algebra, here's a simple argument: first, just make sure that you know where the points $(x,y)=(0,0)$, $(1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$ and $(-1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$ are located in the $(x,y)$ plane. Then plug these values into the formulas; you get $(u,v)=(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, respectively. This means that those three points are in fact the reference points defining the $(u,v)$ coordinate system. So you get the $u$ and $v$ axes by rotating the $x$ and $y$ axes 45 degrees counterclockwise.

Comment: (For this argument to work, it's of course important that it's a *linear* change of variables.)

Comment: I think I begin to understand it, maybe I just need a bit more time. But ty so far for your effort :)
(Now I can finish the job and go the rest of the way myself)